# Spring OAUTH2 usage for two different type of authentication

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

We are using OAUTH2 token mechanism to protect REST webservices. Is there possibility of configuring two possible Authentication mechanism in single token generator and validate it.

1. authentication(based on userId and password).
2. authentication(based on merchantId and password).

So that it can be used to generate valid tokens and user being authenticated. This type mechanism is needed to protect  mobile based rest services and web application using webservices. correct if am wrong.

Comment: The generic answer is "oauth has very little to say about how to authenticate the token granter, so you are free to do what you want." I don't quite follow what you need though, so it's hard to be more specific. What's a merchant id, and how do you authenticate a user in that scenario (or don't you need to)?

Comment: @DaveSyer to be more specific we have a portal user to be autheticated as well as a mobile user to be autheticated. Both need oauth security and token authentication for suqsequent api calls.

Comment: So a merchant is a user, and the client in that case is a webapp ("portal")? I don't see any problem with the OAuth2 model for this, but you still haven't really asked a specific question.

Comment: Merchant is authenticated from with separate userid and password and Mobile user is authenticated with separate userid password both credentials comes from different tables can we accommodate this with OAUTH

Comment: Moblie App is a android application installed on mobile not accessed with the url

Comment: I don't know what that last comment was about (Moblie App). But as I said already, OAuth2 has virtually nothing to say about authentication, so you are free to do whatever you like.